# Vue - How to use computed properties correctly in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some computed properties with different values, may I ask anyway to organize my data?

```
computed: {
  totalCoin() {
    const state = this.$store.state.ApiState.totalCoin
    let val
    if (state === 0) {
      val = 0
    } else if (state === null) {
      val = undefined
    } else {
      val = state
    }
   return val
  },
  totalGem() {
    const state = this.$store.state.ApiState.totalGem
    let val
    if (state === 0) {
      val = 0
    } else if (state === null) {
      val = undefined
    } else {
      val = state
    }
   return val
  }
  repeatedly...
}
```

Note: Every results value will return from VueX to a component by computed properties

```
getToken() {
  return this.$store.state.userToken
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this to improve readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think you could write getters separately in the Vuex file.

```
const getters = {
    getTotalCoin(state){
        return state.totalCoin == null? undefined : state.totalCoin;
    },
    getTotalGem(state){
        return state.totalGem== null? undefined : state.totalGem;
    }
}
```

- Then, you can use mapGetter in your Vue component. It maps store getters to local computed properties:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    // map `this.totalCoin` to `this.$store.getters.getTotalCoin`
    ...mapGetters({totalCoin: 'getTotalCoin', totalGem: 'getTotalGem'})
  }
}
```